# '(QMessageBox::Icon)1u' cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, qt

I'm getting the following error when compiling the codes below in Qt:

```
In member function 'void MaFenetre::ouvrirDialog()'
'(QMessageBox::Icon)1u' cannot be used as a function
```

Any idea what may be wrong ?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MaFenetre.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MaFenetre fenetre;
    fenetre.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**MaFenetre.h**

```
#ifndef MAFENETRE_H
#define MAFENETRE_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>

class MaFenetre : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    MaFenetre();

public slots:
    void ouvrirDialog();

    private:
    QPushButton *m_boutonDialog;
};

#endif // MAFENETRE_H
```

**MaFenetre.cpp**

```
#include "MaFenetre.h"

MaFenetre::MaFenetre() : QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(230, 120);

    m_boutonDialog = new QPushButton("Ouvrir la boîte de dialogue", this);
    m_boutonDialog->move(40, 50);

    QObject::connect(m_boutonDialog, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ouvrirDialog()));
}

void MaFenetre::ouvrirDialog()
{
    QMessageBox::Information(this, "Titre de la fenêtre", "Bonjour et bienvenue à tous les Zéros !");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`QMessageBox::information`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#information): notice the lowercase `i`.

`QMessageBox::Information` is [an enum value](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#Icon-enum).

Comment: Amazing naming convention! :-)